# Authentication error in jenkins on using sudo

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, ssh, jenkins, sudo

I have sh script in jenkins which has sudo ssh command and I am getting this error

```
Warning: Identity file key.pem not accessible: Permission denied.
Host key verification failed.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I have found solutions saying add

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

these lines in /etc/sudoers but still its not working.

Comment: problems with not permissions, may be in your script use ssh on remote  machine?

`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`
- error if you want run action without terminal(for write pass/etc).

Comment: @amisuno when I run it in terminal its fine problem is when jenkins runs it.

Comment: i know, because jenkins doesn't have terminal.

Comment: @amisuno so how do I solve it??

Comment: try add to sudoers `NOPASSWD: ALL`

like this : `jenkins ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
sudo su    
visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

add add following line at the end.

```
jenkins ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: I need to restart?

Comment: the best answer ever. I was struggling for hours on google.

Answer (score 0):

username ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL in sudoers worked in ubuntu server 12.04.2

Comment: Please provide more context for your answer