# Run sudo within Jenkins dockerfile pipeline

Tags: jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, sudo

I am setting up a Jenkins pipeline (declarative script) using a Docker container agent built from a Dockerfile. I want one of the build stages to fetch dependent packages (Debian packages, from Artifactory, in my case) and then install them within the Docker container. Installing those packages (using `dpkg`, in my case) needs super-user permission, and thus `sudo`. How do I set up the pipeline and/or Dockerfile to enable that?

At present, my Jenkinsfile is somewhat like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            filename 'Dockerfile.jenkins'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Set up dependencies') {
            steps {
                sh 'rm -rf dependent-packages && mkdir dependent-packages'
                script {// Fetch packages from Artifactory
                    def packageserver = Artifactory.server 'deb-repo-srv'
                    def downloadSpec = ...
                    packageserver.download(downloadSpec)
                }
                sh 'sudo dpkg -i -R dependent-packages/'
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

And my Dockerfile is like this:

```
# Set up the O/S environment
FROM debian:9

# Add the build and test tools
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install \
   cmake \
   doxygen \
   g++ \
   libcppunit-dev \
   make \
   libxerces-c-dev
```

Because I am using a Dockerfile agent, [simply adding the `jenkins` user to the `sudoers` file of the Jenkins server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940612/authentication-error-in-jenkins-on-using-sudo) will not work.